# singularity workflow design

Tags: parameters, containers, singularity-container

I'm new to singularity and am setting up my first container.  I want to set up the container to run only one type of analysis where a user can provide 3 parameters (ie. names of files).   There are a number of commands I want to apply to the 3 provided files.    My question is how do I set up the container so that the default operation (ie. %runscript or similar) will take user input in the form of some parameters and perform the desired analysis.

On the user end they would run something like:
`singularity run -B /path/to/files the_container.simg file1 file2 file3`
and the suite of tools I have in my container could be applied.  A toy example of what I want to do is something like:

```
join file1 file2 | sort | uniq | join file2
wc -l file1
wc -c file2
echo "finished"
```

Would the recommended approach be to wrap the container in a script such that the commands I want to run are just individually passed to the container?  Ideally I'd like the user interface to hide (or at least not be obvious) to the user as the idea is to use a container to create reproducible results at a number of centres and we don't want people to be tinkering with parameters at each of the steps that the container will provide.

thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to evaluate the parameters. If you're okay with using `/bin/sh`, you can have it directly in the `%runscript`. e.g.,

```
%runscript
    if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "You must give 3 files"
        exit 1
    fi
    file1="$1"
    file2="$2"
    file3="$3"
    join $file1 $file2 | sort | uniq | join $file2
    wc -l $file1
    wc -c $file2
    echo "finished"
```

If you'd rather use a different language, you can pass the arguments from `%runscript` to a custom written script (bash, python, R, perl, etc.) Make sure this file is copied in the definition file and either in the path or call it with the absolute path. e.g.,

```
%files
    my_script.py /opt/bin

%runscript
    exec python /opt/bin/my_script.py $@
```

Using `exec` here is also important. Replacing the current process with the new one helps to ensure that singularity is able to kill any child processes if it receives an interrupt (ctrl-c, OOM, etc). It was an issue for older versions (v2) of singularity, and is probably still the case for current ones.